# Avoid affecting bibliography typesetting, when converting from Markdown to PDF with pandoc, though YAML parameters

Tags: biblatex, line-spacing, pandoc, markdown

I am writing a thesis in Markdown and converting it to PDF through pandoc. My uni requires 1.5 line spacing in thesis documents, and I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883525/set-double-spacing-and-line-numbers-when-converting-from-markdown-to-pdf-with-pa)
post as a guide.

I've set

```
header-includes:\linespread{1.5}
```

in the YAML haeder of my .md file, and it is working fine.

My problem is that this parameter also affects the way the bibliography is rendered at the end of the document, making my citations also 1.5 line spacing.
I would like to avoid this behaviour, somehow specifying to alter only the main text body, or setting a different property just for the bibliography like `\linespread{1}`

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Welcome! There are various ways to do this in (La)TeX, but hopefully somebody will answer who knows `pandoc`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Mwe]

```
--- 
format: pdf
header-includes:
- \linespread{2}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
--- 

Your text. \lipsum[1][1-5]

\linespread{1.0}\selectfont

# References

Your references. \lipsum[2][1-5]
```